# mongoose.populate() returning an empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express

I know, this is one of the popular questions out there. On populate I expect it to return the user with his posts, but it's returning an empty array of posts.

Here is my User model.

**User.js**

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    posts: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Post"
    }]
}, { timestamps: true })

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema)
module.exports = User
```

**Post.js**

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const postSchema = new Schema({
  postTitle: { type: String, required: true },
  postDescription: { type: String, required: true },
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
}, { timestamps: true }
)

const Post = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema)
module.exports = Post
```

`router.get("/posts/:id", usersController.getUserPosts)`

**usersController.js**

```js
    getUserPosts: (req, res) => {
        User.findById(req.params.id).populate("posts").exec((err, posts) => {
            if (err) console.log(err)
            console.log(posts)
        })
    }
```

I'm getting this:

```js
{ posts: [],
  _id: 5e4e3e7eecd9a53c185117d4,
  username: 'rick',
  email: 'rick@gmail.com',
  createdAt: 2020-02-20T08:08:30.878Z,
  updatedAt: 2020-02-20T08:08:30.878Z,
  __v: 0 }
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: How do you export your `mongoose.model` for postSchema and userSchema?

Comment: @onuriltan like this 
```const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema)
<br>
module.exports = User```

Comment: Hi @hellraiser999, did you find a solution to this? I'm experiencing the same issue